# How to resize a UISwitch?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I have made a [custom UISwitch (from this post)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/694848/custom-uiswitch-app-store-approval). But the problem is, my custom texts are a bit long. Is there any way to resize the switch? [I tried `setBounds`, did not work]

**Edit:**

Here is the code I used:

```
@interface CustomUISwitch : UISwitch    
- (void) setLeftLabelText: (NSString *) labelText;
- (void) setRightLabelText: (NSString *) labelText;    
@end

@implementation CustomUISwitch

- (UIView *) slider 
{ 
    return [[self subviews] lastObject]; 
}
- (UIView *) textHolder 
{ 
    return [[[self slider] subviews] objectAtIndex:2]; 
}
- (UILabel *) leftLabel 
{ 
    return [[[self textHolder] subviews] objectAtIndex:0]; 
}
- (UILabel *) rightLabel 
{ 
    return [[[self textHolder] subviews] objectAtIndex:1]; 
}
- (void) setLeftLabelText: (NSString *) labelText 
{ 
    [[self leftLabel] setText:labelText]; 
}
- (void) setRightLabelText: (NSString *) labelText 
{ 
    [[self rightLabel] setText:labelText]; 
}
@end

mySwitch = [[CustomUISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

//Tried these, but did not work
//CGRect aFrame = mySwitch.frame;
//aFrame.size.width = 200;
//aFrame.size.height = 100;
//mySwitch.frame = aFrame;

[mySwitch setLeftLabelText: @"longValue1"];
[mySwitch setRightLabelText: @"longValue2"];
```

Comment: Are you using UISwitch (from your subject) or UICustomSwitch (from your link)?  The [UICustomSwitch class](http://www.catamount.com/blog/?p=1063) is actually a UISlider.

Comment: but it inherits UISwitch, how can it be a slider?

Comment: UICustomSwitch inherits from UISlider.  Which one are you using?  Your code says CustomUISwitch, your subject says UISwitch, but the link you gave points to a UICustomSwitch implementation?  We can't answer your question very well unless you say which of the 3 you really meant!

Comment: Sorry, Now I have added the code.

Answer (score 190, accepted):

The simplest way is to resize it, as a view:

```
 UISwitch *mySwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] init];
 mySwitch.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.75, 0.75);
```

and you don't have to care about anything else!

Comment: Problem is that when we do this it pixelate the switch ... Any other way ?

Comment: This has bugs on iOS 7. You will see some extra gray color when it's off.

Comment: but effect looks bad

Answer (score 29):

Here is the swift 3 version of mxg answer:

```
let mySwitch = UISwitch()
mySwitch.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.75, y: 0.75)
```

Answer (score 7):

Many controls are meant to be a specific size. If you were implementing this yourself, you would override `setFrame:`, adjust the frame parameter to match your control's required size, and then pass that to `[super setFrame:]`.

If you subclass a control that has this behavior, there's really no way to override it because your subclass will inherit the superclass's implementation of `setFrame:`, which modifies your frame rectangle. And there's no way to set the frame of your control without calling `[super setFrame:]`.

You'll most likely have to inherit from `UIControl` and implement the properties/behaviors you want from `UISwitch` manually to work around this.

Comment: Confirmed. Went to UISwitch.h... it has this comment in initWithFrame: "// This class enforces a size appropriate for the control. The frame size is ignored."

Answer (score 4):

UISwitch is not designed to be customized.

I think the your best solution is to download one of the custom switch implementations mentioned in the other question that you referred to.  Either [UICustomSwitch](http://www.catamount.com/blog/?p=1063) or [RCSwitch](http://osiris.laya.com/projects/rcswitch/).  They both should be able to handle wide labels.

Comment: I used UICustomSwitch here... but can't resize it... long labels become wrapped.. RCSwitch works.. thanks

Answer (score 3):

There is no option for resizing uiswitch in xib, so need to create and resize it in controller class,

```
     UISwitch *onoff = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 10)];
     onoff.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.50, 0.50);
     [self.view addSubview:onoff];
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution in code:

```
UISwitch *mySwitchNewsletter = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(varSettingsSwitchNewsletter_x, 
                                                                           varSettingsSwitchNewsletter_y, 
                                                                           varSettingsSwitchNewsletter_width, 
                                                                           varSettingsSwitchNewsletter_height)];
if (mySwitchNewsletter != nil) {

    [varCommerceSettingsView addSubview:mySwitchNewsletter];


    float mySwitchScaleFactor = (varSettingsSwitchNewsletter_scale / 100.0);


    CGFloat dX=mySwitchNewsletter.bounds.size.width/2, dY=mySwitchNewsletter.bounds.size.height/2;
    mySwitchNewsletter.transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-dX, -dY), mySwitchScaleFactor, mySwitchScaleFactor), dX, dY);

    mySwitchNewsletter release];
}
```

Where varSettingsSwitchNewsletter_scale is an int from 0 to 100 (%).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to resize switch put through the Storyboard or nib, You can subclass UISwitch and override awakeFromNib method:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.75, 0.75);
}
```

Select the switch control and change it's class to your custom switch class.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
// Just in case someone trying to hard code UISwitch in Xcode 6.4 the following is working
// in .h
@property UISwitch * onoff;

// in .m

self.onoff = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(160, 40, 0, 0)];
_onoff.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.50, 0.50);
[self.view addSubview:self.onoff];
```