# Swift, Xcode - Increasing the size of a UISwitch

Tags: xcode, swift, size, uiswitch

I am making my app 'universal' (used on iPhone and iPad) and I have found ways of increasing the size of everything except for UISwitches. Is there a way of doing so?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6817448/3769927) by the user [mxg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/193718/mxg), just use the following code:

```
 mySwitch.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.75, 0.75)
```

Of course, you have to change `mySwitch` to whatever the name of your variable/IBOutlet is.

Answer (score 8):

**Swift 3 / 4:**

```
switch.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.75, y: 0.75)
```

Answer (score 5):

**Xcode 9.2 & Swift 4**

```
switch.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.75, y: 0.75)
```

Answer (score 2):

Making a custom one is simple. If you need ideas on how to do so, or would just like to use the one I wrote, try [SwiftySwitch](https://github.com/Sethmr/SwiftySwitch). It allows for a good bit more customization than the default UISwitch gives you, and you get direct access to all of it on the storyboard.

I don't recommend the other ways because Apple does not like having their tools altered in ways they were not meant to be.