# UIBarButtonItem change size

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a Switch and two Bar Button Items and I want to decrease the size of these items. As I understood it is very difficult if it is possible. Are there any solutions for this?

Comment: for size of buttons https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34891973/change-width-of-a-uibarbuttonitem-in-a-uinavigationbar-in-swift

Comment: for switch https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30492731/swift-xcode-increasing-the-size-of-a-uiswitch

Comment: @V_rohit Unfortunately the first link didn't help me. I can only change the width of a button a little, but not a height.

Comment: can you show the code of bar button items

Comment: @V_rohit I add button in storyboard and tried to replace left button like in the example from your first link. If needed I will make a small project and upload it to GitHub.

Comment: it's because NavigationBar has fixed height of 44

Comment: @V_rohit And? Can I change the height of a button in Navigation Bar?

Comment: I tried to change the height of button but it couldn't but I change the width

Comment: You can also makes button without using navigation bar

Comment: @V_rohit But I need a navigation bar. So thanks for the help.

Comment: Here is the link about navigation bar https://youtu.be/zS-CCd4xmRY you can see here