# UISwitch customization?

Tags: iphone, ios, customization, uiswitch

Is possible to add images to an UISwitch background,like when the state is ON (be one background) and  when the state is OFF (another background image)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12400239/uiswitch-with-custom-image

Hopefully that helps :)

Answer (score 2):

To change the background color (not image) all you have to do is below.  This changes the off color for all UISwitch controls in realm.

```
[[UISwitch appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor brownColor]];//Off Color
_locationSwitch.onTintColor = [UIColor orangeColor];//On Color
```

If you want to use image, use the following cool hack of using the segmented control.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5088099/1705353

If you want to write a lot of code, you can write your own control. Valeriy Van pointed to: https://github.com/homick/iPhone-Snippets/tree/master/General

Also another resource is: http://www.raywenderlich.com/23424/photoshop-for-developers-creating-a-custom-uiswitch with code at: http://cdn2.raywenderlich.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/CustomSwitchResources.zip

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest you to follow [Custom UISwitch & App Store approval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/694848/custom-uiswitch-app-store-approval/1729409#1729409) to have a better idea, which is suggesting you to create a custom switch control.

Answer (score 0):

You can recreate a custom `UISwitch` by subclassing `UIControl`. By doing this you can have full control over what the switch looks like. You can look take a look at `SevenSwitch`. A custom `UISwitch` replacement I've created. The on/off colors can be customized to your liking.

https://github.com/bvogelzang/SevenSwitch

Comment: Please disclose any [affiliations](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) and do not use the site as a way to promote your site through posting. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).