# UISwitch with custom image

Tags: ios, uiswitch

I need to customize UISwitch by changing background color as well as knob(holder) image as shown in below image.Is it possible to customize UISwitch without app getting rejected.

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISwitch_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: This is a good blog post about this: http://www.raywenderlich.com/23424/photoshop-for-developers-creating-a-custom-uiswitch

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's an `onTintColor` property you can set on UISwitch. If you need to change the handle image as well, have a look at [DCRoundSwitch](https://github.com/domesticcatsoftware/DCRoundSwitch).

Comment: Thanks for help H2CO3.DCRoundSwitch is really awesome...they have not given any option for customizing knob image..we can only change the size & tintcolor of switch...

Comment: @niks as it's opensource, you can modify it to have custom images. (Btw you can upvote/accept answers that helped.)

Comment: look @ dcroundswitch examples. It shows how to customize the knob